# Really strange Eclipse error when attempting to Compile C++ code, looks like my code is never being deleted

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm fairly new to c++ and decided to start learning by creating several basic projects.  About halfway through I realized I was getting the same compiler errors when building my solutions, even though I was changing my code.  I figured I had errors somewhere, so I decided to slowly undo until my errors went away.  But, the same compiler errors were still there.  I kept using undo until the only code that was left was:

```
    #include <iostream>
```

These were the errors printed to my console: 
../src/client.cpp:10:18: error: Note.h: No such file or directory 
../src/client.cpp:12: error: 'bst' is not a namespace-name 
../src/client.cpp:12: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token 
../src/client.cpp: In function 'int main()': 
../src/client.cpp:16: error: 'bst' has not been declared 
../src/client.cpp:16: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope

The first error was due to a mispelling of "Node.h".  I fixed the spelling mistake and the error persisted.  But, I only have 1 line of code, and apparently line 16 contained an error.

HAS anybody ever had an issue like this before?  I've been searching for a solution all night and havent had any luck.  I'm running osx 10.6.8 (64bit) with a the newest 32bit version of eclipse.  It started for no apparent reason.  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you save the file after editing it?  Sometimes that doesn't occur automatically.  And sometimes it's necessary to clean and rebuild the project because the timestamps get out of whack or whatever.  All IDEs seem to have these problems to varying degrees.

Comment: I do all of those things habitually.

Comment: Next thing to do is to look for a missing semicolon.

Comment: I'd like to see the whole code. I think the environment has something to do with it. MS Visual C++ won't tell me about any errors until I compile the program. I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but reading your question makes me think that the environment compiles the program automatically without running it.C# allows parts of the code to get automatically compiled, in order to find errors before the user compiles the whole program. But I have heard that C++ can't do that because C# is more advanced in some ways.